# Wrong spacing around guillemets under csquotes

Tags: spacing, punctuation, csquotes

With XeLaTeX, polygossia and csquotes updated today, I get an asymetrical spacing between the enclosed text and the French quotation marks:

```
Blabla1 « blabla2 “blabla3” blabla4» blabla5
```

without any spacing right after blabla4, instead of:

```
Blabla1 « blabla2 “blabla3” blabla4 » blabla5
```

with the following code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,oneside]{report}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{french}

\begin{document}
Blabla1 \enquote{blabla2 \enquote{blabla3} blabla4} blabla5
\end{document}
```

There is no problem with normal quotation marks (which don't require any spacing).

How can I get `\enquote` to give the expected result?

Comment: I always thought that `csquotes` didn't interface well with `polyglossia`, though I see now that version `v5.2a` [2017/02/03]) of `csquotes` does not (any longer?) make this precise claim.  But FWIW, the font is irrelevant to the problem, while I can only reproduce the problem using `xelatex`, not `lualatex`. Can you (as a workaround) switch engines?

Comment: As far as I can see the support of polyglossia for french punctuation with xelatex is still broken: https://github.com/reutenauer/polyglossia/issues/145. I wouldn't use polyglossia if you don't need it for some other language but `\usepackage[french]{babel}`.

Comment: My current work makes an extensive use of `polyglossia`, switching to `lualatex` wouldn't be worth it for this document...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a current texsystem (texlive 2018 or miktex) and

```
      Package: polyglossia 2018/04/07 v1.43
```

the problem seems to have been resolved. The output with xelatex of the example is

[image]